# how to determine dpi size of a pdf & djvu

Tags: pdf, dpi, djvu

As the title says how would I determine the dpi of a pdf or a djvu document?

I am looking for a proper linux solution as opposed to running adobe acrobat professional under wine.

Comment: PDF files per-se are vector graphics and can be scaled indefinitely  . Some embedded elements, such as images, can be raster images. Is it the DPI of these elements you want to know?

Comment: Yes maybe I'll see if I can perform a lossless extract say png and determine the dpi of the image that way. It's an image I am dealing with in the pdf, no text. I'll update if I discover anything.